# Why doesn't ls -U list files in alphabetical order?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, ls

On my Xubuntu install, in some folders, if I list all the files with `ls -U`, sometimes they are not listed in alphbetical order. For example, once I had it list every single file in alphabetical order except one single file that came before all the others (it started with the letter `g` and it came before the `a`'s. All the other `g`'s were in the place I expected them to be in).

How does `ls -U` decide the order to list files in?

Answer (score 1):

As per man ls:

> -U     do not sort; list entries in directory order

Otherwise the default behavior is

> Sort entries alphabetically if none  of  -cftu‐ vSUX nor --sort is
> specified

Directory order refers to the order in which the files are internally stored in the file system. Different FS:s use different criteria, so the order depends on the FS itself.

Comment: What does directory order mean?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

According to `man ls`, the `-U` option forces ls to use the directory order in listing the files.

Comment: What is directory order?

Answer (score 0):

Answers saying `-U` means "do not sort; list entries in directory order" are right, but the phrase "directory order" or more descriptive "the order in which the files are internally stored" is misleading in some cases.

Some filesystems (virtual or [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)) do not store anything, they retrieve data on demand. The order you get from `ls -U` in a filesystem like this may be random(-ish).

Imagine a filesystem that aggregates files from several remote servers in one local directory. Let's assume name collisions are not an issue. To list the files as fast as possible the filesystem queries the servers asynchronously, whichever server delivers its listing first will be listed first. Conditions in the network and on the servers can certainly affect how fast and in what order the responses get to the local computer, therefore they will affect the order of files. It's possible to build such filesystem. In it there is no internal storage and there is no strict order; so there is certainly no order in which all the files you observe are internally stored.

`ls -U` uses the order the filesystem *returns*. If the filesystem stores the files internally then most likely it will return an array reflecting the internal order (whatever this means for this particular filesystem); but it may not. In general the order may depend on anything.